# Android auto focus change

Tags: android

i want to have a set of buttons and the focus on buttons should change periodically first i want to try it with 2 buttons.this is my main.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"    
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"    
    android:orientation="vertical" >    

    <Button    
       android:id="@+id/number_button"    
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"    
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"   
       android:layout_gravity="center"    
       android:layout_weight="0.72"    
       android:focusable="true"      
       android:gravity="center"    
       android:text="@string/number"    
       android:textSize="10pt" android:clickable="true"  
       android:focusableInTouchMode="true"/>   

  <Button  
       android:text="@string/contact"    
       android:textSize="10pt"    
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"    
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
       android:id="@+id/contact_button"  
       android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_gravity="center"   
       android:focusable="true" android:gravity="center"  
       android:focusableInTouchMode="true"/>    

</LinearLayout>
```

in the source code i have used FOCUS_LEFT,RIGHT and all other options ,but i am getting a run time exception. the orientation is set as vertical in linear layout.Please help me to sort out this problem, if anybody know how to set the timer option as well post it here

here is the code

```
package com.example.helloandroid;

import android.app.Activity;  

import android.os.Bundle;  

import android.util.Log;  

import android.view.View;  

import android.widget.Button;  

public class HelloandroidActivity extends Activity {  

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */  
    @Override  
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
        // Object o=null;  
        // o.toString();  
        // TextView tv = new TextView(this);  
        // tv.setText("Hello Andriod");  

        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Button mybtn= (Button)findViewById(R.id.number_button);
        mybtn.requestFocus();

        try
        {
        Button mybtn2= (Button)mybtn.focusSearch(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
        mybtn2.requestFocus();

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {

            Log.e("focus change","focus failed",e);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: what RuntimeException? can you put a StackTrace here?

Comment: Guys please answer my question ASAP, it would be of immense help because it is required for my project...

Comment: @Marek sebera : It is NULL pointer Exception

Comment: Kumar: post an StackTrace, I don't think NPE is related to your layout structure, as long as you don't need to modify these buttons at runtime

Comment: i am not getting how to post it ,it is not allowing me paste it here, please tell me how to post it here... could it be the problem with linear layout, do i need to use relative layout??

Comment: no, NPE is problem in Runtime code, try remove all code but leaving onCreate with setContentView.

Comment: no use yaar, i have tried it.cab u guess any other mistake. i have even tried with relative layout.still no use

Comment: post from stacktrace atleast the exception line , like Null pointer exception at ....

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException at com.example.helloandroid.HelloandroidActivity.onCreate(HelloandroidActivity.java:26) the problem is at   Button mybtn2= (Button)mybtn.focusSearch(View.FOCUS_DOWN); statement

Comment: Guys please respond to the question, any solution??

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you is finding a control in mybtn. Inside your activity you should call focusSearch in Activity context. Try this:

```
Button mybtn2 = (Button) focusSearch(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
if (mybtn2 != null)
  mybtn2.requestFocus();
```